# C++ Universal Unicodes

Tags: c++, unicode

I had a quick question and couldn't find an answer anywhere else. Basically I was trying to make a universal function to return the proper unicode (instead of making literals) as shown below in the std::string getUnicode() function. The \xe2\x99\xa and cardType are being treated as two separate strings in the output, which causes a "?" followed by the cardType number.

In this case:

```
cout << "\xe2\x99\xa0"; //prints out a symbol, GOOD
cout << "\xe2\x99\xa" << 0; //prints out "?" followed by 0. BAD
cout << card.getUnicode(); //prints out "?" followed by 0. BAD
```

Any ideas? 4-6 month beginner to C++.

```
#ifndef CARD_H
#define CARD_H

#include <map>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

enum CARD_TYPE {SPADE = 0, CLUB = 3, HEART = 5, DIAMOND = 6};

class Card {

    private:
        int number;
        CARD_TYPE cardType;

    public:
        Card(CARD_TYPE, int);
        void displayCard();

        int getNumber() {
            return number;
        }

        CARD_TYPE getCardType() {
            return cardType;
        }

        /* Returns Unicode Value for this Card Type */
        std::string getUnicode() {
            std::stringstream ss;
            ss << "\xe2\x99\xa" << cardType;
            return ss.str();
        }

};

#endif
```

Comment: I don´t understand what you want. What is "returning proper Unicode" for you? The code could make *some* sense with UTF8... And where is the "output"? Please a MVCE.

Comment: cout << card.getUnicode(); //that's the "output". For hearts, spades, diamonds, and clubs, the unicodes are all the same except for the number at the end, which I'm dynamically trying to append the appropriate number to the end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is talked about in the C++ standard, section 2.14.5, paragraph 13:

> [Example:
>
> ```
> "\xA" "B"
> ```
>
> contains the two characters `'\xA'` and `'B'` after concatenation (and not the single hexadecimal character `'\xAB'`). — end example ]

The problem is that `'\xa'` is being treated as a single character (hex value `0xa` is 10 in decimal, which maps to the `\n` (line feed) character in [ASCII](http://www.ascii-code.com/)/UTF). The `cardType` does not get "appended" to the escape sequence. In fact, the escape sequence is evaluated at compile time, not runtime (which is when the card type gets evaluated).

In order for this to work, you need to do something like:

```
 ss << "\xe2\x99" << static_cast<char>(0xa0 + cardType);
```